# ElasticSearch : List all _source keys for a given terms query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all the sub-fields in the _source field instead of the documents when running a "terms" ElasticSearch query (or any other query).

Let's say I have documents with categories and many other data like color, size, weight, ... Those fields are dynamic, I don't know which ones will be there.

Document example :

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "entity_id": "1",
        "is_in_stock": "1",
        "weight": null,
        "color": null,
        "name": "My Document",
        "description": "Hello World",
        "categories": [
        "4185",
        "4626"
        ]
    }
}
```

Some documents have a color, but not all, so is it possible to obtain all the non-null fields for a specific query, like this one :

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms" : { "categories" : ["5581"] }
  }
}
```

The expected result would be something like (given the provided document is the only one in my index) :

```
{
    "took": 42,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "category_att": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "cosmetique": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "entity_id",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "is_in_stock",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "name",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "description",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "categories",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Do you need all fields which are not null for that specific query? Could you please elaborate your example more?

Comment: Yeah, same here. I don't understand the question, more info should be provided.

Comment: I'm very new to ES, so my vocabulary is probably pretty bad. I edited my question to try and make it better. I hope it's more clear now.What I want is actually a list of available facets for a category of products. I can get the possible values of the fields using aggregations, but not the list of the fields themselves.